# Finding the adjoint of $L$ where $Lf = \int_0^T \exp(A(T-t))\pmb b f(t)\;dt$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

$L:L_2[0,T] \to \mathbb R^n$

$$
Lf = \int_0^T \exp(A(T-t))\pmb b f(t)\;dt
$$

I'm supposed to show that $L^*=\pmb b^T \exp(A^T(T-t))$.

The inner product is over $\mathbb R^n$ since $Lf \in \mathbb R^n$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Lf, \pmb y \rangle &= \pmb y^T\left(\int_0^T \exp(A(T-t))\pmb bf(t)\;dt\right)
\end{align*}
$$

It's be easy if I could separate $f(t)$ from $\int_0^T \exp(A(T-t))$ but since these are multiplied together I can't distrubte the integral through so I don't know how to disentangle $f(t)$ from the $L$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that on *one side* of the equation of adjointness it's the inner product of $\Bbb R^n$, however the other side should utilize the inner product of $L^2([0,T])$, hence the integral would be introduced, and luckily we don't need to carry out $f(t)$ or the exponential part, but *move inside* the inner product with ${\bf y}$.

Specifically, we have to prove $\langle Lf,\, {\bf y}\rangle_{\Bbb R^n}\ =\ \langle f,\, L^*{\bf y}\rangle_{L^2([0,T])}$.
Using the suggested $L^*$, the right hand side becomes
$$\int_0^T f(t)\cdot{\bf b}^\top\exp(A^\top(T-t)){\bf y}\, dt$$

Now observe that ${\bf b}^\top\exp(A^\top(T-t)){\bf y}$ is a scalar (for each $t\in [0,T]$), and hence it equals to its own transpose ${\bf y}^\top\exp(A(T-t)){\bf b}$.

Comment: I think I need a little more help understanding $\langle Lf, \pmb y \rangle_{\mathbb R^n} = \langle f, L^*\pmb b\rangle_{L^2([0,T])^*}$.

I'm trying to understand is how $f(t)$ was able to receive an integral and it seems like $\langle f, L^* \pmb y\rangle$ isn't well defined since the right side is a vector and the left side is a scalar.

Comment: No, actually $L^*{\bf y}$, for a fixed vector $\bf y$, should be an element of $L^2([0,T])$. And, it is: it's the assignment $t\mapsto {\bf b}^\top\exp(A^\top(T-t)){\bf y}$ scalar-to-scalar. It's continuous so (square) integrable over a finite interval. Any bounded linear map $L:U\to V$ between Hilbert spaces has its adjoint $V\to U$.

Comment: We only use here that $\exp(A\cdot(T-t))$ is a continuous function of $t$ outputting square matrices (and that it respects the transpose).